# Background Processes in PHP

Tags: php, background, process

I am fairly new to PHP Scripting.  I'm writing a game that initiates a Lottery every 24 hours.  I would like this to happen at a certain time, say 3pm, regardless of users logging on to the page.

So, if 10 days goes by that no one has logged in, I would like the lottery to have run 10 times.

I saw something for "ignore_user_abort" but I'm not familiar with this and I'm kind of afraid to use it.  Is this the best way to go?  Or is there a more reliable way to go?

Any ideas? And keep in mind, I'm new to this!

Comment: Sounds like you need a [cron job](http://unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use a scheduler outside of PHP such as [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to run a PHP script at set times.

Something like:

```
0 15 * * * /path/to/php /path/to/yourscript.php
```

Here's a tutorial:
http://www.sitepoint.com/introducing-cron/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a Cron job for this, if you are running Linux. Google 'Cron Job'

That way, like you said, the script will run at 3 PM regardless of who is currently accessing the site.